# XmlSerializer.serialize() creates only header

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

When I'm trying to serialize my list of customers i get file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

No exception thrown.
I'm pretty sure it was already working, but i probably changed something somewhere and now I have no idea why it's not working anymore.

I have class CustomerList

```
[XmlRoot("Customers")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Customer))]
public class CustomerList
{
    [XmlArray("CustomerList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Customer")]
    private List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();
    private int position = -1;
...;
}
```

which does contain items of customer class

```
[XmlType("Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private string surname = string.Empty;
    private string phone = string.Empty;
    private string email = string.Empty;

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("Surname")]
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surname; }
        set { surname = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("Phone")]
    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("Email")]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email= value; }
    }
...;
}
```

And this is serialized with

```
private static Type[] extra = { typeof(Customer) };
private XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerList), extra);

public void Serialize(CustomerList Customers)
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
    serializer.Serialize(fs, Customers);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are all private. `XmlSerializer` can only serialize *public* properties and fields. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx):

> XML serialization is the process of converting an object's public properties and fields to a serial format (in this case, XML) for storage or transport.

and later:

> To control the generated XML, you can apply special attributes to classes and members. For example, to specify a different XML element name, apply an `XmlElementAttribute` to a public field or property, and set the `ElementName` property.

I suggest that you convert your private fields into public properties (not public fields).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Yes, the public properties can have whatever implementation you want (although they must have both public get *and set* parts). Unless there's any actual logic in the properties though, you might as well just use automatically implemented properties.

Comment: TY so much. I changed List<Customer> Customers to private from public without realizing this.